# How to avoid maximum memory allocation with concurrent.futures() usage?

Tags: python, python-multithreading, python-3.8

Providing a snippet below of some code I'm using that runs fine, but over the course of about 5 minutes, eventually starts throwing `malloc()` type errors due to using too much memory on my laptop.

As you can see, I've even tried using forced `gc.collect()` statements and explicitly `del`eting variables immediately, to no avail.

Code:

The `user_guids` and `user_groups_list` objects are both basic lists with string data in each element. The `update_user_groups{}` function makes an API call and logs the result to a database, then returns.

**Edit:** I have tried different values for `WORKER_THREADS` and it eats memory no matter what. I'm currently using between 5 and 10 while testing. Lowering the max workers does slow down the issue, but eventually fails with same memory error.

Current code (working, but eats memory):

```
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=WORKER_THREADS) as executor:
    for user in user_guids:
        future = executor.submit(update_user_groups, user['Guid'], user_groups_list)
        future.add_done_callback(print_future_result)
        del future
        gc.collect()
```

I've also tried it like this (eats memory as well):

```
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=WORKER_THREADS) as executor:
    futures = [executor.submit(update_user_groups, user['Guid']) for user in user_guids]
    concurrent.futures.wait(futures, return_when=concurrent.futures.ALL_COMPLETED)
```

I need it to wait until all futures are done as this runs in a Windows service and simply "loops" again once it's complete. Is there a way to use `futures` like this without eating memory? Is there an alternative "multithreaded" approach that can perform the same work without the memory issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a lot of commentary on this one, so I'll answer my own question with a not-so-great "answer"... but it did work. Changing NOTHING with the code, I simply updated to the 64-bit version of Python and it started working without issue. Didn't even use up the same amount of memory as before. The "cap" I was getting at 2.5GB was a red flag to me that screamed 32 bit problem, so I switched to 64-bit, rebuilt my virtual environment, and re-ran the code. Works great now, and memory seems to be managed much better!